# Consumer lag in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

We are having 48 partitions on a topic and 16 jvms running each with listener concurrency as 3(so 48 listener threads listening to 48 partitions to achieve parallelism).
Each message would take 3-5s avg in order to process.
The configuration is as follows on the consumer side

- auto commit is set to false
- max.poll.records is set to defaults(500)
- listener ack-mode is set to RECORD as we have to make sure we commit the msg back only if our backend remote call is succesfull.

With this setup, we are seeing a consumer lag of 4-5 msgs while the producer is publishing msgs.
What would be the best approach in this kind of situation where we want to cut down the lag and increase the throughput? As each txn is critical and we would not like to commit unless backend call is processed and keep this atomic, is there a better way to address this?

Comment: You could try reducing the poll interval, but I feel like 5 messages or less is negligible lag

Comment: You already got a very low consumer lag. If you wanted to reduce the lag even further, please find out if the lag is due to workers being busy processing messages - if so, increase the number of consumers on the same consumer group. (You can go up to 48) If the workers are idle when you see lag, reduce the poll interval can help.

Comment: Lag is going beyond 150 in prod when there is peak traffic and poll interval is default 5mins. We have 48 consumer threads in a consumer group.